# R function for identifying values from one column in another?

Tags: r

I have two different data frames, each of them consisting of a list of "genes" and a list of "interactors" (other genes). Is it possible with R to check if there any "genes" from one list that are also present in any of the columns of "interactors" from the other data frame, and vice-versa?

I am quite new in R, so perhaps there is an easy way to perform this, but I don't even know how to look for it.

Thanks in advance!
Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

please can you show a sample of your data?

In any case, I guess the following is what you need:

```
df_common<-data.frame(df[which(df$genes %in% df$interactors),])
```

it is checking which elements in the column "genes" in the data frame df are also present %in% the column "interactors" in the same data frame

Is it this what you are looking for? if not, please paste input and desired output